# Error at using useState for an array that i fetched from an API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook, and I get this error
when I'm typing

> setProducts(pr)

*Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: an object with keys {userId, id, title, completed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const pr = await response.json();
    console.log(pr);
    setProducts(pr);

    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, [url]);

  return { loading, products };
};

function App() {
  const { loading, products } = useFetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{loading}</h1>
      <h2>{products}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is `console.log(pr);` logging? An object?

Comment: an array of json objects

Comment: React doesn't know how to render arbitrary objects. You need to use `.map()` on your array, and transform each object into JSX which can be rendered - what output are you expecting?

Comment: @radurbalau try this one out. ` <h2>{JSON.stringfy(products)}</h2>`

Comment: Try to map over products if it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to render list of Objects you can not directly print them to the UI.
Instead you can render them using map which will return the list of html/react components.

```
    function App() {
      const { loading, products } = useFetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
      );
      return (
        <div>
          {products.map((product) => <h2 key={product.id}>{product.title}</h2>)}
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```